# Pschopy joystick support

Tags: python, psychopy

I need to use joystick to get X and Y movements in Psychopy. But I get the following error when I run the example of Psychopy Joystick.

```
##### Running: C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy-1.81.02-py2.7.egg\psychopy\demos\coder\input\joystick_universal.py #####
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy-1.81.02-py2.7.egg\psychopy\demos\coder\input\joystick_universal.py", line 19, in <module>
    winType=joystick.backend)#as of v1.72.00 you need the winType and joystick.backend to match
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy-1.81.02-py2.7.egg\psychopy\visual\window.py", line 347, in __init__
    self._setupGL()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy-1.81.02-py2.7.egg\psychopy\visual\window.py", line 1394, in _setupGL
    self._setupPyglet()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy-1.81.02-py2.7.egg\psychopy\visual\window.py", line 1228, in _setupPyglet
    pyglet.window.get_platform().get_default_display().get_screens()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\win32\__init__.py", line 157, in get_screens
    _user32.EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, enum_proc_ptr, 0)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: expected LP_RECT instance instead of int
Exception AttributeError: "'Window' object has no attribute 'useNativeGamma'" in <bound method Window.__del__ of <psychopy.visual.window.Window object at 0x06C92A70>> ignored
```

When I try to use pygame.joystick, I am not able to handle keyboard events and therefore I am not able to quit the execution